# How can i wrap any methods with logger?

Tags: c#, logging

There is a sample method call via service instance.

```
 _logger.LogDebug("Create runned !");
 await _service.Create();
_logger.LogDebug("Create completed successfully");
```

How can i write log before enter and after called method more efficient ?

For example:

```
using(Log.Wrapper())
{
   await _service.Create()
}
```

Comment: In your example, where would the log message text come from? Do you _really_ need all the logs in the first place, especially as "Information" rather than a lower severity such as "Debug" or "Trace"? Do you know about [ILogger scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#log-scopes)?

Comment: Actually, we can say Debug log for this example. Just i want to know enter and exist log debug info to understand how log proceed and called times.

Comment: What's the environment? What .Net Version? There are different ways to [decorate](https://pmichaels.net/2022/05/13/using-scrutor-to-implement-the-decorator-pattern/) Services.

Comment: Core 5.0 @Fildor

Comment: The blog post I linked to above contains a link to an excellent introduction video by Nick Chapsas on Youtube on Scrutor. I am not saying this is the perfect solution for you, but you may be interested to look into that, because I really do think you might want to go in that direction, at least.

Comment: You could abuse `IDisposable` and write a wrapper that starts a stopwatch in its ctor and logs a message with the elapsed milliseconds on dispose. Or you could implement a _decorator_ that wraps your service and writes a "before" log, invokes the decorated method, and then logs an "after" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to use some tool to rewrite the produced IL-code from your program, that way you can inject logging post compilation. [This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17275/Really-Easy-Logging-using-IL-Rewriting-and-the-NET) seem to describe the practice, and I have seen commercial tools, but it is not something I have used.

The approach I tend to use is to create a decorator, often using a helper method do the actual logging from a central place:

```
public class MyLoggingDecorator : IMyInterface{

public MyLoggingDecorator(IMyInterface backing, ILogger logger){...}

private T LogBeforeAndAfter(Func<T> method, [CallerMemberName]string caller = null){
    logger.Info("Called: " + caller);
    var result = method();
    logger.Info("Call " + caller + " completed");
    return result;
}
int IMyInterface.MyExampleMethod(int parameter) => LogBeforeAndAfter(() => backing.MyExampleMethod(parameter));
```

This has some overhead, and is not as efficient as just calling the log directly in each method, but it can help to make the code more compact. And any overhead is probably less then the cost to do the logging in the first place.

Your 'using'-example is probably not something I would recommend using in a public API. But if you only use it in your own code, and your colleagues  don't complain, I do not really see any problem with it. Just create something like this class

```
public class LogBeforeAndAfter : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger log;
    private readonly string caller;

    public LogBeforeAndAfter(ILogger log, string caller)
    {
        this.log = log;
        this.caller = caller;
        log.Info("Called: " + caller);
    }

    public void Dispose() => log.Info("Call " + caller + " completed");
}
...
public static LogBeforeAndAfter LogBeforeAndAfter(this ILogger log, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "") => new (log, caller);
```